# Weak convexity in graphs

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, metric-spaces, convex-analysis

As we know, a finite undirected graph induces a metric space on the set $V$ of its vertices. A convex set of vertices is defined as a set $S \subseteq V$ such that for any $u,v \in S$, all shortest paths (or geodesics) joining $u$ and $v$ are contained in $S$. Now I wonder if anybody has studied a relaxation of this definition, that requires that *at least one* shortest path joining $u$ and $v$ be contained in $S$. In Euclidean space both definitions are obviously equivalent, since for every pair of points $x,y$ there is a unique geodesic joining them. Are there other metric spaces, besides graphs, where two points may be joined by more than one geodesic?

Comment: Natural examples of metric spaces, where two points may be joined by more than one geodesic, should be manifolds endowed with a metric.

Comment: Also a notion of [intrinsic metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric)  may be helpful here.